# Why can std::vector be more performant than a native array?

Tags: c++, vector, std

In a comparison on performance between Java and C++ our professor claimed, that theres no benefit in choosing a native array (dynamic array like `int * a = new int[NUM]` ) over std::vector. She claimed too, that the optimized vector can be faster, but didn't tell us why. What is the magic behind the vector?

PLEASE just answers on performance, this is not a general poll!

Comment: Did you consider asking your professor for her reasoning?

Comment: You contradict yourself in your own question

Comment: Also, I would point out that this is flatly incorrect: *"theres no benefit in choosing std::vector over a native array."* A vector will manage the array allocation for you, so there is a very straightforward benefit in that it's much harder to leak the array allocation by using a vector.

Comment: Ugh, comparisons between languages are always wrong. Especially performance comparisons.

Comment: @Griwes I think he worded it wrong, he actually is just talking about c++

Comment: @cdhowie right. but I'm talking about performance. Neither safety nor convenience.

Comment: It's hard to believe that a vector could be faster than an array, as fast perhaps but not faster. In any case it's the wrong consideration, performance issues are normally totally irrelevant when making this choice. Safety, convenience and functionality are much more important.

Comment: It can be faster as in less programmer time and easier to manage efficiently, but in the end vector just manages an array for you so it can not be faster performance wise.

Comment: Your instructor needs to clarify what they mean by "native array", as pretty much every answer below is hung up on dynamic memory management. There is no such logic required  for a native array in the *langauge* (I'm not talking about the standard *library* provisions; just the *langauge*).

Comment: Ah, there we go. Thanks for the edit. Suddenly the answers below are applicable to the question now-asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any super optimized code with lower level stuff like raw arrays can beat or tie the performance of an `std::vector`. But the benefits of having a vector far outweigh any small performance gains you get from low level code.

1. vector manages it's own memory, array you have to remember to manage the memory
2. vector allows you to make use of stdlib more easily (with dynamic arrays you have to keep track of the end ptr yourself) which is all very well written well tested code
3. sometimes vector can even be faster, like qsort v std::sort, read this [article](http://tilander.org/aurora2/Comparing_standard_sort_and_qsort/), keep in mind the reason this can happen is because writing higher level code can often allow you to reason better about the problem at hand.
4. Since the std containers are good to use for everything else, that dynamic arrays don't cover, keeping code consistent in style makes it more readable and less prone to errors.

One thing I would keep in mind is that you shouldn't compare a dynamic array to a `std::vector` they are two different things. It should be compared to something like [`std::dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray) which unfortunately probably won't make it into c++14 (boost prolly has one, and I'm sure there are reference implementations lying around). A `std::dynarray` implementation is unlikely to have any performance difference from a native array.

Comment: Your second point is also true of arrays. Both are considered to have random-access iterators.

Comment: @chris true but with dynamic arrays you have to keep track of the end ptr yourself

Comment: So I reread the OP's question a couple of times: Who said anything about *dynamic* arrays?

Comment: @WhozCraig I assumed that is what he was referring to by native arrays

Comment: Apparently everyone else does as well, but hopefully the distinction is obviously important. The truly "native" arrays offered up purely by the *language* are of the form `Type var[N];` and `Type var[] = {initializer list};` and for construction you simply cannot beat `sub esp, N*sizeof(Type)` on the allocation side. Once construction is done, they're on equal ground (obviously).

Comment: @WhozCraig I'll edit the question since that is almost surely what he is talking about

Comment: @aaronman don't edit too fast. The OP just changed the conditions of the question to be in lock-step with your answer. (+1 btw).

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks, appreciate the input, also would bet `std::array` is essentially optimized to `Type var[N]` in compiled code

Comment: @aaronman every implementation I've ever seen has `std::array<>` as just a wrapper to that anyway, so it would seem reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is benefit of using vector instead of array when the number of elements needs to be changed.
2. Neither optimized vector can be faster than array.

Answer (score 0):

The only performance optimization a `std::vector` can offer over a plain array is, that it can request more memory than currently needed. [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) does just that. Adding elements up to its [`capacity()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) will not involve any more allocations.

This can be implemented with plain arrays as well, though.

Comment: I can allocate a native array bigger than I need, a.k.a. reserving.

Comment: @Thomas I guess that's why I noted that this can be done with arrays as well. If you feel the need to comment, don't just parrot what has already been said.